# Python - download a file that needs a cookie set

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests, urllib2, urllib

I have the following code

import urllib

```
f=open('ondemand.txt','r')
for line in f:
    urllib.urlretrieve (line, "1.webm")
```

In theory, it works, but the URLs need a cookie set. How would I go about it in the above scenario or do I need to move to `urllib2` or `requests`?

I have tried using requests as follows:

```
import requests
f=open('ondemand.txt','r')
cookie = {'nameofcookie': 'valueofcookie'}
for line in f:
    response = requests.get(line,cookies=cookie)
    print response.text
    fName =  line.split('/')[-1]    
    with open('/tmp/'+fName, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
```

However I get the error:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Error>
        <Code>MissingKey</Code>
            <Message>Missing Key-Pair-Id query parameter or cookie value</Message>
    </Error>
```

Thanks

Comment: With requests it is trivial, just use http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#cookies to set a cookie, and [How to download image using requests](//stackoverflow.com/q/13137817) to do the download.

Comment: The issue here seems to be that you are setting the wrong cookies or not adding needed parameters. You can do a request to httpbin.org/cookies to verify the cookies are being sent correctly. Without knowing what cookies or parameters need to be set it will be challenging to answer your question.

Comment: I think I need to add multiple cookies

Comment: I think the best way it to use selenium and web browser. Login or whatever and then download.